# Firefox OS: Callback before app terminates

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events, firefox-os

Is there a callback function in Firefox OS before it crashes the whole app? because I want to send a crash report.

Answer (score 0):

No, the linux kernel will send a kill signal to apps when memory pressure occurs.  We don't/can't expose this to JavaScript.  See [this page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Debugging_OOMs) for info on debugging if your app is running out of memory.

Comment: Not sure. It's simply just a callback function.

Comment: What's the callback doing?  If invoking any new API it's possible you've found a platform bug.  FxOS and APIs are still relatively new.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Nick! with regards for my callback, i'm going to use it send logs to the server or probably save it to db. It's most likely the same as Firefox Desktop, if it crashes user has an option to send logs to the server or not.